# InfoPath form rows to multiple rows in SharePoint list

Tags: 2010, list, infopath

I am developing an InfoPath form for use on a SharePoint 2010 server that has multiple rows of data. I would like each row on the form to populate a new row in a SharePoint list. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. There is a setting somewhere, that I cannot find atm, that allows you to use a single form to publish multiple repeating data list items as individual utems.

Comment: If someone could tell me, that'd be great. It seems there's one way to do this by first creating a SharePoint List template in InfoPath Designer. However, all the fields are required to be repeating. Kind of annoying but at least means I get the data as I want.